# Schema.org markup for a vacation rental website?

Tags: schema.org

I have built a vacation rental website which allows users to add their home to my site, this will include all info, map, reviews and photos.

I am not sure how to mark up each property detail page with the correct Schema.org data.

I have been looking and `LodgingBusiness` looks close, but these are not hotels, just someone's home to rent for a few weeks. I would ideally tag the name, photo, description, map, reviews, location too, but unsure about the actual main category.

Answer (score 0):

For the places which get rented, you can use the [`Accommodation`](http://schema.org/Accommodation) type. There are more specific types, like [`Apartment`](http://schema.org/Apartment), [`Suite`](http://schema.org/Suite), [`House`](http://schema.org/House) etc.

It offers the properties you are looking for:

- `name`, `image`, `description`
- [`hasMap`](http://schema.org/hasMap)
- [`review`](http://schema.org/review)
- [`address`](http://schema.org/address) (or [`containedInPlace`](http://schema.org/containedInPlace))

For documentation about all the accommodation-related types and properties, see [*Markup for Hotels*](http://schema.org/docs/hotels.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks. That makes sense to use Accommodation but on the page on schema it says less than 10 domains, so would it be best to use something like 'Product', I have looked on other rental sites and one has this as the main wrapper for the whole home, then split up into review/imageObject etc.

Comment: @ChrisD: You can ignore the statistics published on Schema.org (they get updated rarely, and only a subset of domains is taken into account). As the accommodation types were introduced with the last version, I guess the stats are still from days *before* they were published in Schema,org’s core. -- You shouldn’t use `Product` instead (nor in addition). To represent the commercial aspect, you should use an `Offer` in addition (like documented).